# C# WinForm passing a name chosen in a combobox to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures, combobox

I got a table of Homepages with two of them as Root/Main/Parent Websites(localDB, Dataset). I want to implement a stored proc. which lists all parents of a website and show results [id, parentID, name] in a DataGridView.

I got following sproc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetIDbyID (@childname varchar(50)) AS

;With CTE  (ID
        ,   name
        ,   parentID
        ,   Level) AS
(SELECT e.ID
        , e.name
        , e.parentID
        , 0 AS Level

    FROM page AS e
    WHERE e.name LIKE @childname

UNION ALL

SELECT    e.ID
        , e.name
        , e.parentID
        , Level+1

    FROM page AS e
    INNER JOIN CTE AS h
    ON h.parentID = e.ID
    )
SELECT DISTINCT ID
              , name
              , parentID
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ID
```

Executed I'm getting this query in which I can insert a website

```
USE [C:\...DATABASE1.MDF]
GO

DECLARE @return_value Int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetIDbyID]
        @childname = N'**Page..**'  //How to insert the page here that is selected in the combobox???

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I managed it to build up a connection to the database and list the whole table in a combobox. The DataGridView with columns and connection to the SP already exists, too. Now my wish is that when I select a site in the combobox, a DataGridView get filled immediately with the values of the SP. Is that even possible with this CTE?

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Tag the dbms product used. (That SP doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: sounds like you want to use the on ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged to refresh/bind your datagrid.  You are posting your SQL code but this is really more of a c# question as far as I can tell so you should post that code too

Comment: @Matt Thank you! I wanted to, but since there was no problem with my code, I just wanted to be sure this SQL is kind of compatible. The answer below was what I needed :-)

Comment: @jarlh I know what ANSI is, but just for my interest, how should that SP look like the right way? I took parts of it of a tutorial and changed it just the way it works for my db. And for the future I would like to do it appropriate

Comment: If you're using MS SQL Server, the ANSI SQL version of the procecure wont run. MS SQL Server (and most other dbms products) has it's own implementation of stored procedures. That's why you should specify which dbms product you're using!

Comment: I understand! Yes I'm using MS SQL. Next time I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually like to create a separate procedure to fill the datagridview and then call it from whatever event(s) I want to change the data.  Here is an example that should get you started:

```
public void fillDataGridView()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetIDbyID]", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childname", comboBox.SelectedValue); //add as many parameters as you need
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells); //this just autosizes the columns to their contents and is optional
            }
        }
}
```

You could call this from the SelectedIndexChanged event and/or create a button that will execute it on click.

Comment: Thank you! Just did it this way with a Button and it works fine. Thanks for the fast reply!